# Search Button in my Javascript Weather Application doesn't seem to work

Tags: javascript, html

I'm writing my weather app in JavaScript. I have issues with search button, data of application don't change after you put a name of city and press enter button. What should I change in my API variable (const api) or in my fetch to make it work? Or maybe I have problems with my api data? Here's my HTML code:

```
<html> 
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <mate name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content= "ie=edge">
    <title> Weather App</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class ="app-wrap" >
      <header>
        <input type= "text" autocomplete="off" class="search-box" placeholder="search for a city">
      </header>
      <main>
        <section class="location"> 
          <div class="city"> Istra, Ru </div>
          <div class="date">Friday, 24 April 2022</div>
        </section>
        <div class="current">
          <div class="temp">+14<span>°c</span></div>
          <div class="weather"> Cloudy</div>
          <div class="hi-low">+12°c/+15°c</div>
        </div>
      </main>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Javascript code:

```
const api= {
  key: "6aa96f9b0d0d34ee6efd29438b57baae",
  baseURL: "api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=London,uk&APPID=6aa96f9b0d0d34ee6efd29438b57baae"
}

const searchbox= document.querySelector(".search-box");
searchbox.addEventListener("keypress", setQuery);

function setQuery(event) {
  if(event.keyCode === 13) {
    getResults(searchbox.value);
    console.log(getResults);
  }
}

function getResults(query) {
  fetch(`${api.base}weather?q=${query}&units=metric&APPID=${api.key}`).then(weather => {
    return weather.json();
  }).then(displayResults);
}

function displayResults(weather) {
  let city= document.querySelector(".location .city");
  city.innerText= `${weather.name}, ${weather.sys.country}`;
  
  let now= new Date();
  let date= document.querySelector(".location .date");
  date.innerText= dateBuilder(now);
  
  let temp= document.querySelector(".current .temp");
  temp.innerHTML= `${Math.round(weather.main.temp)}<span>°c</span>`;
  
  let weather_el= document.querySelector(".current .weather");
  weather_el.innerText= weather.weather[0].main;
  
  let hilow= document.querySelector(".hi-low");
  hilow.innerText= `${Math.round(weather.main.temp_min)}°c / ${Math.round(weather.main.temp_max)}°c`; 
}

function dateBuilder (d) {
  let months= ["January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December"];
  let days= ["Sunday", "Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday"];
  
  let day= days[d.getDay()];
  let date= d.getDate();
  let month= months[d.getMonth()];
  let year= d.getFullYear();
  
  return `${day} ${date} ${month} ${year}`;
}
```

Comment: What do the browser developer tools tell you?

Comment: Is the `key` supposed to be the same as the `APPID`?

Comment: I can't see the search button

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to catch errors coming from async calls ot you won't be able to properly debug, your API call is returning a 404 status error since you are using a wrong URL for fetch:

```js
const api = {
  base: 'https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/',
  key: '6aa96f9b0d0d34ee6efd29438b57baae',
};

const searchbox = document.querySelector('.search-box');
searchbox.addEventListener('keyup', setQuery);

function setQuery(event) {
  console.log('event.keyCode', event.keyCode);
  if (event.keyCode === 13) {
    getResults(searchbox.value);
    console.log(getResults);
  }
}

function getResults(query) {
  fetch(`${api.base}weather?q=${query}&units=metric&APPID=${api.key}`)
    .then((weather) => {
      console.log(weather);
      return weather.json();
    })
    .then(displayResults)
    .catch((e) => console.log(e.toString()));
}

function displayResults(weather) {
  let city = document.querySelector('.location .city');
  city.innerText = `${weather.name}, ${weather.sys.country}`;

  let now = new Date();
  let date = document.querySelector('.location .date');
  date.innerText = dateBuilder(now);

  let temp = document.querySelector('.current .temp');
  temp.innerHTML = `${Math.round(weather.main.temp)}<span>°c</span>`;

  let weather_el = document.querySelector('.current .weather');
  weather_el.innerText = weather.weather[0].main;

  let hilow = document.querySelector('.hi-low');
  hilow.innerText = `${Math.round(weather.main.temp_min)}°c / ${Math.round(
    weather.main.temp_max
  )}°c`;
}

function dateBuilder(d) {
  let months = [
    'January',
    'February',
    'March',
    'April',
    'May',
    'June',
    'July',
    'August',
    'September',
    'October',
    'November',
    'December',
  ];
  let days = [
    'Sunday',
    'Monday',
    'Tuesday',
    'Wednesday',
    'Thursday',
    'Friday',
    'Saturday',
  ];

  let day = days[d.getDay()];
  let date = d.getDate();
  let month = months[d.getMonth()];
  let year = d.getFullYear();

  return `${day} ${date} ${month} ${year}`;
}
```

```html
<div class="app-wrap">
  <header>
    <input type="text" autocomplete="off" class="search-box" placeholder="search for a city" />
  </header>
  <main>
    <section class="location">
      <div class="city">Istra, Ru</div>
      <div class="date">Friday, 24 April 2022</div>
    </section>
    <div class="current">
      <div class="temp">+14<span>°c</span></div>
      <div class="weather">Cloudy</div>
      <div class="hi-low">+12°c/+15°c</div>
    </div>
  </main>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
const api= {
  key: "6aa96f9b0d0d34ee6efd29438b57baae",
  baseURL: "http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/"
}

const searchbox= document.querySelector(".search-box");
searchbox.addEventListener("keypress", setQuery);

function setQuery(event) {
  if(event.keyCode === 13) {
    getResults(searchbox.value);
  }
}

function getResults(query) {
  const url = `${api.baseURL}weather?q=${query}&units=metric&appid=${api.key}`;
  fetch(url).then(weather => {
    return weather.json();
  }).then(displayResults);
}

function displayResults(weather) {
  let city= document.querySelector(".location .city");
  city.innerText= `${weather.name}, ${weather.sys.country}`;
  
  let now= new Date();
  let date= document.querySelector(".location .date");
  date.innerText= dateBuilder(now);
  
  let temp= document.querySelector(".current .temp");
  temp.innerHTML= `${Math.round(weather.main.temp)}<span>°c</span>`;
  
  let weather_el= document.querySelector(".current .weather");
  weather_el.innerText= weather.weather[0].main;
  
  let hilow= document.querySelector(".hi-low");
  hilow.innerText= `${Math.round(weather.main.temp_min)}°c / ${Math.round(weather.main.temp_max)}°c`; 
}

function dateBuilder (d) {
  let months= ["January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December"];
  let days= ["Sunday", "Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday"];
  
  let day= days[d.getDay()];
  let date= d.getDate();
  let month= months[d.getMonth()];
  let year= d.getFullYear();
  
  return `${day} ${date} ${month} ${year}`;
}
```

```html
<html> 
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <mate name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content= "ie=edge">
    <title> Weather App</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class ="app-wrap" >
      <header>
        <input type= "text" autocomplete="off" class="search-box" placeholder="search for a city">
      </header>
      <main>
        <section class="location"> 
          <div class="city"> Istra, Ru </div>
          <div class="date">Friday, 24 April 2022</div>
        </section>
        <div class="current">
          <div class="temp">+14<span>°c</span></div>
          <div class="weather"> Cloudy</div>
          <div class="hi-low">+12°c/+15°c</div>
        </div>
      </main>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

I updated the baseURL value. You don't need to include "q" and "appid" parts there)
Also in the call (URL build) you used wrong parameter name. It's not `base`, but `baseURL`